# Problem with dart sdk and ClipPath widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to use ClipPath widget in my app , but I got this exception :

The current Dart SDK version is 2.15.0.

Because clip_path requires SDK version >=2.16.0-80.1.beta <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because clip_path requires SDK version >=2.16.0-80.1.beta <3.0.0, version solving failed.)

Also after updating the dart sdk from 2.15.0 to 2.16.0-80.1.beta  I am facing the same issue too , I will be happy if someone can help me .

pubspec.yaml : --------------------------------------

```
name: clip_path
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.0-80.1.beta <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter



  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

clippath code ---------------------

```
class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path>{
  @override
  getClip(Size size) {
  return Path()..lineTo(0, size.height)..quadraticBezierTo(size.width/2, size.height, size.width, size.height);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper oldClipper) {
   return false;
  }

}
```

The whole code of main and MyHomePage widget --------

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
     
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
   const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);



  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
   

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final size=MediaQuery.of(context).size;
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(title: const  Text("ClipPath"),),
     body: ClipPath(
       clipper: MyClipper(),
       child: Container(
         width: size.width,
         height: size.height/2,
         color: Colors.blue,
       ),
     ),
   );
    
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to update your pubspec.yaml file and change the sdk version there too.

Comment: environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.0-80.1.beta <3.0.0" , this is the sdk version there ,  but still not working

Comment: Can you add the code where you've added the clippath? Also your pubspec file ?

Comment: I added it , give a look please .

Comment: Could you please execute flutter doctor and share the output ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
flutter channel master

flutter upgrade
```

**If first one not works than try this**

```
flutter channel stable

flutter upgrade
```

Comment: not working bro , i think the problem with vscode , cuz when i click "start Debuging button" it throws that exception above , but  when i use the terminal to run my flutter projects it works and everything is okay , so again if i use any button of vscode gui like get packages or depug button nothing work , if i use the terminal everything is working , this is the problem and i cant fix it till now